# DB2 start tuning needs privilege

Tags: db2

When I run "start tuning" by db2 data studio it gives me the below message. This still happens when I run it under user "db2inst", the default user which I configured when I installed db2 on RedHat 7.2

[image]

Comment: Do the explain tables exist? `select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables where tabname like 'EXPLAIN%'`

Comment: No bro, I didn't find any result after I ran your mentioned query

Comment: Then may be create them? I don't know if there's a function for that in Data Studio, but you can also run this statement: `CALL SYSPROC.SYSINSTALLOBJECTS('EXPLAIN', 'C', '', current_user)`

Comment: Can I run it through linux terminal command ?

Comment: @Eng.Bassel Sure. `db2 connect to mydb ...; db2 "CALL SYSPROC.SYSINSTALLOBJECTS('EXPLAIN', 'C', '', current_user)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Mark Barinstein many thanks to you because you made it easier for me

This worked with me with below two steps :-

1- [db2inst@localhost ~]$ db2 connect to TESTDB

2- [db2inst@localhost ~]$ db2 "CALL SYSPROC.SYSINSTALLOBJECTS('EXPLAIN', 'C', '', current_user)"

Comment: Your answer is the recommended way, another option is (which I find it much easier to remember:-): `db2 -tf ~/sqllib/misc/EXPLAIN.DDL`